# Dual space of $l^p$ is $l^q$.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

I was reading functional analysis from Kreyszig.
While proving that dual space of $l^p$ is $l^q$, I came across a doubt.
I have attached the screenshot.
In this they are applying f to $x_n$ but for that  $x_n$ ,must be in $l^p$ because f is an element of dual space of $l^p$.
I tried proving  $x_n$ is in $l^p$ so I take $|\zeta_1|^p+...+|\zeta_n|^p$which is simplified to $|\gamma_1|^q+...+|\gamma_n|^q$ but now how to proceed?[image]

Comment: You're taking a *finite* sum of numbers, which is guaranteed to be finite.

Comment: but why $\gamma_i$ should be finite?

Comment: $\gamma_k = f(e_k)$ is a complex number.

Comment: yes, and bcs norm of a complex no. will be finite, therefore $\gamma_i$ are finite , right ?

Comment: Yes, the absolute value of a complex number is a real number.

Comment: Okie, got it. Thank you so much.